# How does John Connor saving Kyle Reese in Genisys fit with the previous film?

Tags: the-terminator, the-terminator-series, terminator-genisys

In the  beginning of *Terminator: Genisys*, John Connor saves Kyle Reese when he was a child. How does that fit to the plot of the previous movie, where Kyle Reese is 16 years old and has never met John Connor?

Comment: Because it's a different timeline than Terminator 1

Comment: Being a different timeline from 1 is irrelevant, as the "change of timeline" happens in the story. The scenes we see in the beginning of the film are supposed to be the same timeline as Term. 1 and 2, but they ignore 3 and Salvation.

Comment: @AdiMI : If you are satisfied with my answer, please consider clicking the checkmark to the immediate left of my answer.  This lets us know that your question has been resolved.

Answer (score 6):

## It doesn't fit, and there was no intention that it should fit.

Regarding Kyle Reese being 16 and never having met John Connor before that age, you are referencing *Terminator: Salvation*.

The writers of *Terminator: Genisys*, Laeta Kalogridis and Patrick Lussier, had received advice from Terminator creator James Cameron by way of producer David Ellison, giving them permission to largely ignore both *Terminator 3: Rise of the Machines* and *Terminator: Salvation*, as these films are not well-regarded by fans nor by Cameron himself.

> ...production of another installment [*Genisys*] in the series was set up in collaboration with Skydance Productions, owned by ... David Ellison. The Ellisons made sure to ask for the input of Terminator creator James Cameron, hoping to create something that would get closer to the spirit of the original film and sequel *Terminator 2: Judgment Day*.

([Source](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_Genisys))

In effect, Cameron has distanced himself from the third and fourth films, calling *Genisys* the real "third film".  Therefore, *Rise and the Machines* and *Salvation* have become a different canon from *The Terminator*, *Terminator 2*, and *Terminator: Genisys*, and continuity between *Salvation* and *Genisys* was not imposed.

> Following a screening of *Terminator: Genisys*, franchise creator James Cameron essentially told fans that they could ignore *Terminator 3: Rise of the Machines* and *Terminator: Salvation* when they go to see *Terminator: Genisys*, saying "in my mind I think of [*Genisys*] as the third film."
>
> Cameron has previously revealed that he's not a big fan of either *Rise of the Machines* or *Salvation*. On the other hand, having seen an early screening of *Genisys*, he seemed to approve of the Alan Taylor directed sequel.
>
> "It's being very respectful of the first two films," he says, "and then all of a sudden it swerves and now I’m going on a journey."

([Source](http://comicbook.com/2015/06/08/james-cameron-says-terminator-genisys-is-the-real-third-terminat/))

The upshot of all this is that the two Kyle Reese back stories are elements of different canons.  Cameron tells you to ignore the *Salvation* one in favour of the *Genisys* one...

Answer (score 1):

Like someone said, the two meetings happen in two different timelines, or "universes". So both can be considered canon.

The future scenes in *Terminator: Genisys* are supposed to happen in the original timeline, or at least, the timeline that follows only the first film. In this timeline, Judgement Day happened in 1997.

But *Terminator: Salvation* takes place in the timeline that was altered when Cyberdine was destroyed in *Terminator 2: Judgement Day*, and is the same continuity of *Terminator 3: Rise of the Machines*. In this timeline, Judgement Day happened in 2004 (as shown in the third film), not 1997.

So, in a nutshell, both scenes depicting the meeting of John and Kyle simply happen in two parallel timelines.